# How to stop one childrenlistener when other childrenlistener start in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have two childrenlistener from firebase in the same activity called from a popup menu that has two options. (two options, two childrenlistener).

I need only to run a childrenlistener, that is, if the user presses "option1" their thread is created, and if the user presses "option2", the thread of "option1" is canceled and it only shows the thread data of "option2" and vice versa

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Ruta1Manantiales.this, busLocation);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sentidos, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.toString()){
                        case "option1":
                            _globalString = "option1";
                            loginToFirebase();
                            break;
                        case "option2":
                            _globalString = "option2";
                            loginToFirebase();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show(); //showing popup menu

private void loginToFirebase() {
    // Authenticate with Firebase, and request location updates
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser!=null){
        if(_globalString == "ida"){
            checkIfChildrenExistIda();
        }

        if(_globalString == "vuelta"){
            checkIfChildrenExistVuelta();
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Firebase auth failed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth failed");
    }
}

private void checkIfChildrenExistIda(){
    DatabaseReference fbDb = null;
    if (fbDb == null) {
        fbDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }


    fbDb.child("locations/unidad_1/ida")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // get total available quest
                    int size = ((int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    if (size >= 1){
                        subscribeToUpdatesIda();
                    } else if (size <= 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "No buses available",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}

private void checkIfChildrenExistVuelta(){
    DatabaseReference fbDb = null;
    if (fbDb == null) {
        fbDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }


    fbDb.child("locations/unidad_1/vuelta")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // get total available quest
                    int size = ((int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    if (size >= 1){
                        subscribeToUpdatesVuelta();
                    } else if (size <= 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "No hay camiones disponibles",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}


private void subscribeToUpdatesIda() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("locations").child("unidad_1").child("ida");
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarkerIda(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarkerIda(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            removeMarkerIda(dataSnapshot);
            //Toast.makeText(Ruta1Manantiales.this, "child removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

private void removeMarkerIda(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //Toast.makeText(Ruta1Manantiales.this, "child removed 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

    if (mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        Marker marker = mMarkers.remove(key);
        if(marker != null){
            marker.remove();
        }
    }
}

private void setMarkerIda(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // When a location update is received, put or update
    // its value in mMarkers, which contains all the markers
    // for locations received, so that we can build the
    // boundaries required to show them all on the map at once
    Bitmap markerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bus_marker);
    markerBitmap = scaleBitmap(markerBitmap, 70, 70);


    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap)).title("Ruta 1 - Unidad-Manantiales").position(location)));
    } else {
        mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
    }


    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }

    if (firstLoad) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 13));
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(19.407021,  -102.046595);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 12.9f));
        firstLoad = false;
    }
}

private void subscribeToUpdatesVuelta() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("locations").child("unidad_1").child("vuelta");
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarkerVuelta(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarkerVuelta(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            removeMarkerVuelta(dataSnapshot);
            //Toast.makeText(Ruta1Manantiales.this, "child removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

private void removeMarkerVuelta(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //Toast.makeText(Ruta1Manantiales.this, "child removed 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

    if (mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        Marker marker = mMarkers.remove(key);
        if(marker != null){
            marker.remove();
        }
    }
}

private void setMarkerVuelta(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // When a location update is received, put or update
    // its value in mMarkers, which contains all the markers
    // for locations received, so that we can build the
    // boundaries required to show them all on the map at once
    Bitmap markerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bus_marker);
    markerBitmap = scaleBitmap(markerBitmap, 70, 70);


    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap)).title("Ruta 1 - Unidad-Manantiales").position(location)));
    } else {
        mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
    }


    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }

    if (firstLoad) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 13));
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(19.407021,  -102.046595);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 12.9f));
        firstLoad = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a listener to a reference/query, Firebase returns a reference to that listener. You'll want to hold on to that reference in a member field:

```
ChildEventListener mActiveListener;
```

And then when you attach the listener:

```
mActiveListener = ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  ...
```

Then when you are ready to attach the other listener, first remove the previous one with:

```
if (mActiveListener != null) {
  ref.removeEventListener(mActiveListener);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
your help worked, 
I only added "ref" as a global variable so that it was recognized in the other listener

Comment: if I press the active listener again, the app crashes :(. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.database.Query.removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: That looks like you've set `ref` to `null`.